# C# Using Dictation Grammar and Predefined Grammar alternatively

Tags: c#, .net, nlp, webkitspeechrecognition, houndify

I wanted to create a desktop application in C# that could make use of both Dictation Grammar and Predefined Grammar.To achieve functionality similar to that of Hound by SoundCloud or Google Now or Cortana or Siri for instance. So here's how I intend to use it:

- Firstly, I'd define before hand sentences, I'm sure the user would use like what is X plus Y. (Now it's obvious writing syntax from -infinity to +infinity is the only way to use predefined Grammar here)(What I intend to do is use Dictation Grammar in such a way that it follows these parameters first i.e. listens from "what" "is" "plus" and pass it on to a local variable for processing)
- Secondly, I'd like to know if there's a way to make Dictation Grammar more flexible by filtering it out through predefined sentences by using Regex I guess. It'd go like this.. Suppose I say "what is twenty-five plus a hundred and eight ?" and say the recognition engine interprets it as "What is twenty-five bus and hundred nights" (Note: I actually copy-pasted this!) So I want such interpretations to be mapped to an existing set of conditions set in a if statement-chain or something similar.

Thanks for the help guys :) Note: I don't intend to use 3rd party APIs...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to build or what your goals are, but third party APIs aren't that bad and can save you A LOT of work.  For example, on Houndify.com they already have an arithmetic domain that supports "what is twenty-five plus a hundred and eight" out of the box from both speech and text input.

Either way, good luck.

Comment: Houndify was the main reason why I started the thread. But if we were all to sit back thinking it's the best there is, there'd be no innovation further on! The point being I actually wanted to incorporate it on desktop level for Client Resource management...